# Is there any way to extract name of field when parsing protocol buffer?

Tags: java, java-8, protocol-buffers

I have problem with protocol buffer data. When paring and extracting the data that I want to use with java.

```
message MotherData {

    SonData1 son_data1 = 10;
    SonData2 son_data2 = 10;
}
message SonData1 {
    string my_name = 10;
}
message SonData2 {
    string my_name2 = 10;
}
```

And I want to make Map<String, Something> like this.

1. put("son_data" ,/* SomeData don't care for now */)
2. put("son_data2",/* SomeData don't care for now */)

To make this map I need to extract key as "son_data", "son_data2". So, I try to extract it like this way.

```
Mother mother = Mother.parsefrom(/*Some byte array input including contents of Mother*/);
mother.getSonData1().getDescriptorForType().getName();
mother.getSonData2().getDescriptorForType().getName();
```

But it returns "SonData1", "SonData2" not "son_data1", "son_data2"
Is there any way to extract own's name used in proto?

Answer (score 1):

```
for (Descriptors.FieldDescriptor field : Mother.getDescriptor().getFields()) {
    map.put(field.getName(), mother.getField(field));
}
```